# opening m-files in new volume -- how to make MATLAB default?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, windows-10, matlab

I am dual booting Windows and Ubuntu. My drive D partition in Windows can be accessed from Ubuntu and is called "New Volume". I thought this was great to have this arrangement since I did not set aside a large space for Ubuntu.

Now, I have m-files in the New Volume but when I open them up in Ubuntu (by double clicking them), gedit pops up instead of Matlab. This does not happen to m-files in Ubuntu that are not on New Volume. Anyway, when I select open with, Matlab is not there.

How can I resolve the issue? I plan to clone a git repository here as well in New Volume.

Thanks for your help!